# What does it mean "bash < <( curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )"

Tags: bash, shell

The RVM homepage

http://rvm.io/

recommends people install RVM using

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

What is this syntax? `command <( another_command)`

Can't the original line be? `curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head | bash`

Comment: that's really old and no more relevant

Comment: Even though the specific commands used (and, more particularly, the URL — people are changing `http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/` into `http://rvm.io/` fairly systematically), the question is not really about the URL but about the shell notation ([Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)).  The question is still relevant for the notation (but might be a duplicate of another question; someone else will need to research that).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<(command)` creates a named pipe with the output of the command (or uses an existing `/dev/fd` file), and substitutes the filename of that pipe into the command. `<` then redirects standard input from that given file.

So yes, in this case, this is equivalent to

```
curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head | bash
```

I'm not sure why they suggest the more complicated and less portable version. In some cases, you would prefer the version using `< <()` to the version using a pipe, as the pipe creates a subshell for the command receiving input (in this case, `bash`), while the `< <()` creates a subshell for the command producing output. If you use a pipe, then the command in the subshell can't modify variables in the shell environment, which is sometimes desired (if you wanted to pipe something to a `while read ...` command). However, in this case, the output of the command is just being passed directly to an explicit invocation of `bash`; there is nothing that needs to be run from the parent shell here.

Comment: I believe the reason why this syntax is used is so the script is downloaded completely to a named pipe before being executed. Otherwise, the script may be cut off during transmission, and a truncated script would run (with errors likely.)

Answer (score 4):

See [part 23 of the advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

In short, the effect of the `<( x )` and `>( y )` syntaxes are the following:

- You put them in your command line where a filename is expected
- Enclosed command will either

  - redirect stdout to (`<(x)`), or
  - read stdin from (`>(y)`)

  a temporary file (or a named pipe, bash will manage it), the name of which will be given to your external command.