# What does " | bash" at the end of curl call in terminal on os x mean

Tags: macos, bash, curl, terminal

In a tutorial on how to set up virtual box i came across the following line

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash
```

I got curious on what the "| bash" part means, but i can't find it on google and its driving me nuts. Most likely this is a very n00b question, but I would appreciate if someone could give me an explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096962/what-does-it-mean-bash-curl-http-rvm-io-releases-rvm-install-head

Comment: Nope, to me it isn't a duplicate. I could not quickly have figured out the answer to my question from that post. To me the answer in below is perfect. Clear and precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` or pipe operator will redirect the output of the previous command (`curl` in this case) to `bash`, i.e. the shell.
`bash` itself will execute it.

So whatever the website returns will be executed as a shell script.

This is nowadays typical for installers, but you should be aware of the source (website) and content the URL provides, because it may harm your system.

More on the pipeline: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html